# Finding out-of-order element in linked list

Tags: algorithm, sorting, linked-list

Given a linked list of numbers in nondecreasing order except for a single element, find the single out-of-place element.

I feel like there has to be a simple algorithm for this, but I can't figure it out. You can't really just compare the current number with the last because you have cases like this 1, 2, 5, 3, 5 where 3 would be incorrectly returned as the out-of-place element.

This is my code:

```
Node* fix(Node* head) {
    if (!head || !head->next) return head;

    Node* curr = head;
    Node* prev = head;
    Node* wrongNode = head;
    Node* wrongPrev = head;


    while (curr) {
        if ((!curr->next && prev->val > curr->val) || //if at beginning or end, its outofplace
             (curr == head && curr->val > curr->next->val)) {
            wrongNode = curr;
            wrongPrev = prev;
            break;
        }

        if (curr->next && ((prev->val < curr->val && curr->next->val < curr->val) ||
             (prev->val > curr->val && curr->next->val > curr->val))) { // if both sides of element are either larger or smaller, it might be outofplace. Check by running through the list to see if list is in correct order if you skip the element.
            wrongNode = curr;
            wrongPrev = prev;

            Node* temp = head;
            Node* tempPrev = head;
            while (temp && tempPrev->val <= temp->val) {
                tempPrev = temp;
                if (temp->next == curr) temp = temp->next->next;
                else temp = temp->next;
            }

            if (!temp) break;
        }

        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if (wrongNode == head) head = wrongNode->next;
    else wrongPrev->next = wrongNode->next;
    curr = head, prev = head;


    while (curr && wrongNode->val > curr->val) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if (curr == head)   head = wrongNode;
    else prev->next = wrongNode;
    wrongNode->next = curr;

    return head;
}
```

I basically scan through the list and if I find an element in the beginning that's greater than the next, or the element at the end that's less that greater than the one before, this element must be the out-of-place element.

If that's not the case, I search for an element k that has an element before and after such that they are both either larger than k or both smaller than it. Then, I try and see if the list is in nondecreasing order without k. If it is, k is out-of-place. If not, it must be the next (I think).

Then I insert k into the right place.

There are possible inputs like

1, 0 where 1 or 0 is out of place.

1, 2, 5, 6, 4, 7 where 4 is out of place.

1, 2, 5, 3, 4 where 5 is out of place.

7, 1, 2 where 7 is out of place.

There HAS to be a simpler way to do this. I am just not seeing it.

Comment: `There HAS to be a simpler way to do this. I am just not seeing it.`
Unfortunately, No. There is no simpler way to do this.

You would have to go traversing the whole list, checking what happens to the list if you include the element or exclude it ( More like the Knapsack Algorithm )

The algorithm would be `O(2^n)`. You might have to apply some Dynamic Programming to bring it down to `O(n^2)`

I don't know the exact question, but had the answer of '1,2,5,3,4' would be 3, then the question would be as simple as it looks like

Comment: @AnandUndavia I don't see any need of Dynamic Programming here.

Comment: @heyitsme On what basis are you saying the output of `1, 2, 5, 3, 5` is `3`. Why can't it be `5` ? The series could also look like `1,2,3,5`. Why is it that it can be `only` `1,2,5,5`?

Comment: @vivek When did I say that? The closest thing in my post to your sample input is 1, 2, 5, 3, 4 in which case 5 would be the out-of-order number. In your case, 1, 2, 5, 3, 5, I agree. Either 3 or 5 would work.

Comment: @heyitsme Since you mentioned only 3, I thought so. Anyways, I have added my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Scan the list linearly taking the difference of current and previous element. If the difference is negative, either the current or the previous item is out of place. This can be checked at least in your cases by a trial removal of 'current'. If removing the element causing the negative diff doesn't fix the list, then removing the previous must.

```
List : 1  2  5  6  4  7
diff =    1  3  1 -2  3
Trial: 1  2  5  6  *  7 --> correct
       1  2  5  *  4  7 --> incorrect (no need to check)

List : 7  1  2
diff :   -6  1
Trial: 7  *  2  --> incorrect
Trial: *  1  2  --> correct (no need to test)
```

Answer (score 0):

**ASSUMPTIONS**

- List is in non-decreasing order.
- Length of the list is greater than `2` and there is `at most 1` element out of order.

I have made an attempt in `java`.

**DEFINITION OF LINKED LIST**

```
class ListNode{
    int data;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int d){
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

**ALGORITHM**

- Iterate over the list of elements.
- Now, if current element is greater than next element-

  - If there exists an element even after next element, we move the window of comparison to `current,next,next to next`.
  - If there exists `no element` after next element, we move the window of comparison to `prev,curr,next`.

**Code:**

```
class ListNode{
    int data;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int d){
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] test = {
                        {1,2,5,3,5},
                        {1,2,5,1},
                        {1,2,5,2},
                        {7,1,2},
                        {1,2,5,6,4,7},
                        {1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
                        {1,2,5,3,4},
                        {1,2,5,3,5,6,7},
                        {1,2,5,3,4,4,4},
                        {2,3,2},
                        {3,3,2}
        };

        for(int i=0;i<test.length;++i){
            ListNode head = new ListNode(test[i][0]);
            ListNode temp = head;

            for(int j=1;j<test[i].length;++j){
                ListNode newNode = new ListNode(test[i][j]);
                temp.next = newNode;
                temp = newNode;
            }

            temp = findOutOfOrderElement(head);
            System.out.println(temp == null ? "No out of place element" : temp.data);  
        }        
    }

    private static ListNode findOutOfOrderElement(ListNode head){

        ListNode ptr  = head;
        ListNode prev = null;

        while(ptr != null && ptr.next != null){
            if(ptr.data > ptr.next.data){
                if(ptr.next.next == null){
                    if(prev == null) return ptr;
                    if(prev.data > ptr.next.data) return ptr.next;
                    else return ptr;
                }else{
                    if(ptr.data <= ptr.next.next.data) return ptr.next;
                    return ptr;
                }
            }

            prev = ptr;
            ptr= ptr.next;            
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
3
1
5
7
4
No out of place element
5
3
5
3
2
```